# Matching to multi-line string in bash with word boundary not working

Tags: bash

I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.4.19` to match to a line in a multi-line string (which I'm reading from a file).

File `in.txt`:

```
abc/def/
bar/foo/x
foobar/foo/y
foobar/quux/
```

In this file, with a pattern like `^bar/foo/.*$`, I'm trying to match `bar/foo/` (and not `foobar/foo/y`).

But since it's a multiline string, `^` and `$` will not match each line but rather all of the string. Therefore I'm trying to use `\b` (word boundary) in my regexp.

This is what I'm trying but it's not working.:

```
in="$(cat in.txt)"
re=\\bbar/foo/.*\\b
[[ "$in" =~ $re ]] && echo OK
```

Other patterns I tried and didn't work:

- `re=\bbar/foo/.*\n`
- `re=\\bbar/foo/.*\\n`
- `re=\\bbar\/foo\/.*\\b`
- `re=\\bbar\/foo\/.*\\n`
- `re=\\bbar\/foo\/\(.*\)\\n`

Comment: What do you mean by multi line string here? You just want your regex to match `bar/foo/x` right?

Comment: I want it to match to a single line, but from a multi-line string. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working". Do you mean that `echo OK` is not executed?

Comment: That's correct. I currently use `re=[^\b]*${dir}`, but when I try to append `.*\b to this, doesn't match anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` uses **POSIX.2 regular expressions** for `=~` (see `man 7 regex`) as described here

> ... a '\' followed  by
>          one  of the characters "^.[$()|*+?{\" (matching that character taken as
>          an ordinary character),  a  '\'  followed  by  any  other  character(!)
>          (matching  that character taken as an ordinary character, as if the '\'
>          had not been present(!)), or a single character with no other  signifi‐
>          cance  (matching  that character).

and they don't support `\b` as word boundary delimiter.

Your best option is to match line by line

```
ii=( $(< in.txt) )
for l in "${ii[@]}"
do
    [[ "$l" =~ $re ]] && echo "match: $l"
done
```

Comment: I was able to match to beginning of the line with `re=[^\b]*bar/foo` but not so much luck for matching the remainder of the line. :)

Answer (score 0):

Grep's `P` option supports word boundaries `\b`. So with GNU's grep you could do:

```
in="$(cat in.txt)"                                                         
re="\bbar/foo/[^ ]*"                                                            
grep -oP "$re" <<< $in
```

The output is:

```
bar/foo/x
```

Comment: Unfortunately I only must use bash regex since the number of times I call this operation is a lot. Calling an external process slows it down heavily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to match the wanted line:

```
awk '/^bar\/foo\/*/{print $0}' input_file
```

Hope this helps.